# flutter: [firebase_auth/admin-restricted-operation]ADMIN_ONLY_OPERATION flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

I'm encountering this error when I'm trying to launch an app I was working on 2 month ago it was working okay and it does work on android now but when I'm trying to run it on iOS I get this error
I'm using anonymous method for the Authentication and it's enabled in Firebase what could be the problem?

```
flutter: [firebase_auth/admin-restricted-operation]ADMIN_ONLY_OPERATION
```

Comment: Have you disabled sign ups from Identity Platform by chance?

Comment: no I changed nothing 